# Message Archiving Management on MongooseIM returning feature not implementing

Tags: mongoose-im

I have edited the configuration file of MongooseIM as follows to enable MAM

```
{mod_mam_odbc_prefs, [pm]},
{mod_mam_odbc_arch, [pm]},
{mod_mam_odbc_user, [pm]},
{mod_mam, []}
```

After restarting the server, when i send a message it gets stored in the database tables of MAM (2 entries for each message which i don’t know why).

Now, when i send an IQ stanza to fetch these messages, i get “Feature Not Implemented” error in response.

IQ Sent:

```
<iq type=”get” id=”page1″ to=”exampleserver.com”><query xmlns=”urn:xmpp:mam:tmp”/></iq>
```

When i tried to discover the features using http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info, i get the following response.

```
<feature var=”http://jabber.org/protocol/amp”/>
<feature var=”http://jabber.org/protocol/commands”/>
<feature var=”http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info”/>
<feature var=”http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items”/>
<feature var=”iq”/>
<feature var=”jabber:iq:last”/>
<feature var=”jabber:iq:register”/>
<feature var=”msgoffline”/>
<feature var=”presence”/>
<feature var=”presence-invisible”/>
<feature var=”urn:xmpp:carbons:1″/>
<feature var=”urn:xmpp:carbons:2″/>
<feature var=”urn:xmpp:mam:tmp”/>
<feature var=”urn:xmpp:ping”/>
<feature var=”urn:xmpp:sic:1″/>
<feature var=”vcard-temp”/>
```

Comment: Are you sending the IQ with the correct namespace? As of now MAM in MongooseIM supports version 0.2 (namespace: urn:xmpp:mam:tmp) of the XEP. Maybe you're trying to use version 0.3 (namespace: urn:xmpp:mam:0)?

Comment: i am using namespace: urn:xmpp:mam:tmp. I have already shared the exact IQ i am sending

Comment: this is what i am sending: <iq type=”get” id=”page1″ to=”exampleserver.com”><query xmlns=”urn:xmpp:mam:tmp”/></iq>

Comment: Ahhh, sorry for my sloppy reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're addressing the IQ to `exampleserver.com` while you should either address it to bare JID of the sender (i.e. `someuser@somedomain.com`) or omit the `to` attribute completely - then the server will assume it's directed towards the sender's bare JID. [Section 10.3.3 of RFC-6120](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#rules-noto-IQ) describes handling of IQs with or without the `to` attribute. [The basic query example from XEP-0313](http://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0313-0.2.html#query) uses no `to` attribute in the IQ element.

Comment: thanks erszcz for the help. i removed the to attribute and can now receive all the archived messages. is there any way to receive messages from a certain user. For eg: User A sends a message to User B. User B also sends message to User A. Now can user B request only the messages sent by User A to User B and not all the messages?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please refer to XEP-0313 I linked to in my answer. To be precise, MongooseIM as of now supports version 0.2 of the XEP, which is available here: http://xmpp.org/extensions/attic/xep-0313-0.2.html

Comment: yes i did read that but i am unable to filter the messages. But i am sure i will be able to figure that out after a few tries. else i will get back to you again :)